# Swift 2.0 soap request with Alamofire send xml parameters

Tags: xml, swift, soap, alamofire

I want to do a request to this web service example: http://www.holidaywebservice.com//HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl

I need to send one parameter "countryCode". I don't know how can i do that with alamofire. And how i get the response to parse the xml result.

This is how i did in postman, but i want to know how do the same in swift.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Parsers such as https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi will make it easier for you to parse xml by means of XPath or CSS selectors. You may define your own serializer for it. Take a look at https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper , which is a good example of making your own Alamofire response serializers

Answer (score 2):

Try it

- Will make a POST request
- URL = http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl
- The Parameters are sent to the encoding section
- encoding: .Custom =>
- Created a mutbleRequest
- a. You can take directly URL or b. New URL
- the important is mutableRequest.HTTBody, it is where the soap-message is placed with the necessary values (type String)
- the Headers can vary from according to the web service and API, in one case can have login / password / token or only authorisation
- the line -->  "Content-Type" : or "Content-Length" depends on the situation.
- SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!) is to handle the response, your can see more in [AlamoFire / Usage / Response Handling ] (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

  ```
     Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl", 
  parameters: nil, 
  encoding: .Custom({
     (convertible, params) in
         //a.
         let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as!                NSMutableURLRequest
         // or 
         //b.
         mutableRequest.URL =NSURL(string: theUrlString)
         let mutableReques02 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: theURL!)
         //
         //mutableReques02.HTTPBody =....

         mutableRequest.HTTPBody =       
              "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
              <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <hs:GetHolidaysAvaible>
                <hs:countrycode> UnitedStates</hs:countrycode>
                </hs:GetHolidaysAvaible>
               </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

      return (mutableRequest, nil)}),
   headers: 
      ["Username": "login", // Login API
       "Password": "password" , // Password API
       "AuthenticatedToken" : "35432",  // Authenticated API
       "Authorization": "Basic nasiouynvo8eyt829409", // Authenticated API
      "Accept" :       "text/xml", 
      "Content-Type" : "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", // Type content and charset accept 
      "Accept-Charset" : "UTF-8",])
   .responsePropertyList { response in 
         let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
                  print(xml) 
  }
  ```

*Note* : My English is not very good

Comment: it would help if you added an explanation of your code to your answer

Comment: check now, i try explain

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a pod for mapping XML to objects, called [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper). (uses the same technique as the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper))

You can use the [Requests](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper#requests-subspec) subspec to create easily SOAP requests.

First create your own custom `SOAPMessage`:

```
class HolidayServiceMessage: SOAPMessage {

    var countryCode: String?

    override func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        super.mapping(map: map)

        countryCode <- map["m:countrycode"]
    }
}
```

Then create the SOAPEnvelope like:

```
let soapMessage = HolidayServiceMessage(soapAction: "GetHolidaysAvaible", nameSpace: "http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2")
soapMessage.countryCode = "UnitedStates"

let soapEnvelope = SOAPEnvelope(soapMessage: soapMessage)
```

Finaly send the SOAP request using Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request("http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl", method: .post, parameters: soapEnvelope.toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.soap(withAction: "http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2#GetHolidaysAvaible"))
```

You can map the XML response to swift objects using `XMLMappable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

**I got this from github:**

> Alamofire doesn't have any built in SOAP or XML support, so you'd have
>   to write your own. Fortunately it's straightforward to create a custom
>   response serializer, but the XML parsing is up to you.
>
> As for the parameters, take a look at the documentation and see which
>   of the built in encoding match your use case.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at [SOAPEngine.](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) It supports Swift and seems to be well maintained.

Comment: Any help with that? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867328/how-to-work-with-soap-web-service-and-xml-parsing-in-swift

Comment: It is not free sdk