# How to get data from SOAP in ios 8.

Tags: ios, soap, soap-client

I have requirement for this. I followed some tutorial but none of them giving proper response.

Comment: Try in Swift with Alamofire and SWXMLHash (Library)
Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447337/swift-2-0-soap-request-with-alamofire-send-xml-parameters/36365218#36365218 them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867328/how-to-work-with-soap-web-service-and-xml-parsing-in-swift/36655348#36655348

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. This worked for me.

https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine

Comment: I tried that library but that is licensed and I need to pay some amount. :(

Comment: Use STHTTPRequest or AFNetworking, both are free and easy to integrate.