# IOS and SOAP server

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, wsdl, server

How to work with this kind of server

http://136.243.3.6:8888/wsLoyalty/Loyalty.1cws?wsdl

I mean how to response, request and so on

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447337/swift-2-0-soap-request-with-alamofire-send-xml-parameters/36365218#36365218

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a soap envelope to send request and will need to use XML parsing to read response

[Refer this](https://amoghnatu.net/2014/04/26/consuming-soap-web-services-from-ios-objective-c/)

Comment: But I don't this <soap:envelope> tag on my service. I am not so good in understanding soap, so what should to "soapMessage" variable, like in this tutorial? And what about headers?